# Como analisar impacto em performance de um trecho de código em ADVPL?

Tags: desempenho, advpl

Tenho o seguinte código em ADVPL:

```
Static Function linhaJson(cTabela, cChave, lVerificaExclusao)
    local cTipo
    local xResult
    local cJson := "{"

    dbSelectArea("ZX1")
    ZX1->(dbSetOrder(1))
    ZX1->(dbGoTop())
    ZX1->(dbSeek(cChave))

    While !(ZX1->(EOF())) .AND. cChave == ZX1->(ZX1_FILIAL + ZX1_COD)
        If ZX1->ZX1_TIPO == 'B'
            xResult := &(conv2Json(ZX1->ZX1_CP_PRO, cTabela))
            cTipo := ValType(xResult)//ValType(ZX1->ZX1_CP_PRO) 
            If cTipo == 'C'
                if AllTrim(xResult) != "NULL"
                    cJson += '"' + AllTrim(Lower(ZX1->ZX1_CP_GEO)) + '":"' + ESCENVST(SUBS(AllTrim(xResult),1,ZX1->ZX1_TAM)) + '",'
                EndIf
            ElseIf cTipo == 'N'
                cJson += '"' + AllTrim(Lower(ZX1->ZX1_CP_GEO)) + '":"' + AllTrim(STR(&(cTabela + "->"+ZX1->ZX1_CP_PRO))) + '",'
            ElseIf cTipo == 'D'
                cJson += '"' + AllTrim(Lower(ZX1->ZX1_CP_GEO)) + '":"' + AllTrim(DtoS(&(cTabela + "->"+ZX1->ZX1_CP_PRO))) + '",'
            EndIf
        ElseIf ZX1->ZX1_TIPO == 'S'
            cJson += '"' + AllTrim(Lower(ZX1->ZX1_CP_GEO)) + '":"' + AllTrim(ZX1->ZX1_CP_PRO) + '",'
        ElseIf ZX1->ZX1_TIPO == 'V'
            cJson += '"' + AllTrim(Lower(ZX1->ZX1_CP_GEO)) + '":"",'
        Else //ZX1->ZX1_TIPO == 'N'
            cJson += ""
        EndIf
        ZX1->(dbSkip())
    EndDo
    ZX1->(dbCloseArea())

    cJson := SUBS(cJson, 1, len(cJson) - 1)

    If lVerificaExclusao //Se for excluso
        cJson += ',"data_delete":"' + getCurrentDate() + '" '
    EndIf
    cJson += "}"
Return cJson
```

Sua obrigação única é minerar dados advindos de uma consulta no Protheus e transformar em um JSON para eu consumir no meu servidor. Ele é executado para cada linha de cada mineração que eu faço.

Eu creio que a iteração em `ZX1` para resgatar as mesmas informações em 80.000 linhas da mesma consulta tenha algum peso na performance, porém não conheço nenhum *profiler* para ter certeza do quanto se está sendo dedicado a esse trecho de código em específico. Não tenho segurança para fazer medição de tempo dentro do código sem que essa medição não altere o objeto de medição e sua medida.

> Pela iteração em `ZX1`, me refiro ao processo todo, desde a inicialização com `dbSelectArea("ZX1")` até o *teardown* do laço com `ZX1-> (dbCloseArea())`

Outro ponto de dúvida que tenho sobre performance é sobre `substrings`, nesse trecho: `cJson := SUBS(cJson, 1, len(cJson) - 1)`. Isso poderia gerar alguma fragmentação de memória alocada para as strings a mais do que eu já estou fragmentando. Novamente, não conheço *profiler* que o faça, e dessa vez não tenho conhecimento de como medir de dentro do código memória usada, chamadas de coletor de lixo nem fragmentação.

Então, reitero minha pergunta do título:

Como analisar o impacto em performance de um trecho de código?

A intenção aqui é evitar fazer alguma refatoração desnecessária no código, que no final das contas tenha pouco ganho e que seja difícil de fazer. Apenas para alterar os *hotspots* do trecho de código.

Comment: @Bacco, pois é, não consegui ver como resolver essa macro (`&(conv2Json(ZX1->ZX1_CP_PRO, cTabela))`) estaticamente sem precisar interpretar esse trecho de código... mas algo me diz que existem outros gargalos mais fáceis de serem removidos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Analisando superficialmente o código, se esta *STATIC FUNCTION* `linhaJson()` é chamada muitas vezes, de dentro do mesmo contexto de execução, REMOVA as linhas : `ZX1->(dbGoTop()) e ZX1->(dbCloseArea())`. Você não precisa abrir e fechar o alias `ZX1` a cada *loop*. Isso já vai te dar um com ganho de desempenho, de olhos vendados. E também não precisa posicionar no primeiro registro da ordem para fazer um `DBSeek()`.

Agora, para avaliar o tempo gasto por esta função, e pelas chamadas vindas de dentro dela, a melhor alternativa é usar o *Profiler* do **AdvPL**. Por hora, veja na TDN no *link* [Como executar um Profiler](http://tdn.totvs.com/display/public/PROT/LogProfiler+-+Como+executar). Embora dessa forma o *log* gerado vai gerar informações sobre a rotina inteira, a análise do `console.log` do Protheus Server gerado após a execução da rotina permite identificar quais as funções que foram chamadas de que ponto do fonte, inclusive todas as chamadas da função `LinhaJson()`, e todas as chamadas de funções chamadas de dentro dela.

Comment: Essa `linhaJson` é chamada diversas vezes, garantidamente. Então, nesse caso, supondo que eu continue fazendo o `while` sobre `ZX1->EOF() .OR. cChave == ZX1->(...)`, com esse `ZX1->dbSkip()` no final desse laço, como garantir que a `ZX1` esteja no mesmo local no próxima vez que `linhaJson` for chamado? Sobre o profiler, assim que possível tentarei rodá-lo para identificar os hotspots, realmente não conhecia esse TDN.

Comment: Grande automan! rs Toma meu +1. :)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, se a tabela ZX1 não for alterada durante o processamento, e você tem uma alta incidência de repetições do parämetro cChave, você poderia fazer um cache usando um array STATIC, apenas para a última chave processada. Por exemplo, em três chamadas consecutivas da função onde cChave nao foi alterado, as proximas chamadas nao fariam IO com o DBAccess. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Consegui com sucesso fazer o _profiling_ (mas infelizmente não consegui fazer usando a `linhaJson` acima descrita; tive dificuldades configurando o ambiente de testes, mas isso não vem ao caso). Estou tendo alguma dificuldade em entender tudo da saída do _profiler_, acho muito confusa a documentação da Totvs. Tem alguma TDN relativa ao assunto? Ou então acha que devo postar uma nova dúvida com as informações relevantes do _profiling_?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, existe uma documentação mais rica em detalhes na TDN, porém não está com acesso público liberado -- está restrita aos participantes da TOTVS. Uma boa alternativa é usar uma ferramenta do TDS, que é capaz de gerar e analisar o Profiler de execução -- vide link http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=24347198

Comment: @siga0984, eu até cheguei nessa página, mas não consegui extrair dela as informações que me eram quistas. Todas as informações que ele mostra nos prints da IDE eu consegui discernir/calcular a partir do log do _profiler_, mas [algumas coisas não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346893/64969) (sim, acabei por criar a pergunta =P). Ah, eu prefiro usar o plugin do KillerAll para VSCode do que mexer nesse TDS derivado do Eclipse, me é mais intuitivo e fácil de trabalhar.